# Visual Studio: Use csv file for “Find Text” validation in web performance test not working

Tags: visual-studio, web, performance-testing

I am using csv file for posting the data and checking the response back, where in find text, i want to use the same csv files.

In string body im using :{{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}} which is working fine for posting request.
same thing i passed in find text in validation rule, it doesn't work and i am getting failure for this validation rule.

In validation rule, i am using "Find Text" and passing {{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}}

The "Details" tab show this for the validation rule :

Find Text   Validation  The required text '{{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}}' did not appear in the HTML response. FindText={{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}}, IgnoreCase=True, UseRegularExpression=True, PassIfTextFound=True

Tried using custom validation rule and tried passing context parameter.Same issue.Validation rule for it is below:

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the validation rule you are using and its parameters. Also show the text from the "Details" tab that shows how that validation rule was handled. A good way of showing the rule itself is to add an extract from the ".webtest" file (it is just an XML file that can be opened with Notepad), find the lines starting with `<ValidationRule  Classname=...` and ending with `</ValidationRule>` and copy them into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many places where a ".webtest" allows a context parameter (CP) have a "bind" facility on the property. For example, look at the `Value` property of a "Header" to a request, it has a drop-down list giving access to CPs.

Some properties of a ".webtest" allow CPs to be embedded in the text. For example the `Url` property of a request allows things like `text{{CpOne}}moretext{{CpTwo}}etc`.

Unfortunately there are some properties of a ".webtest" that only allow text and do not expand embedded CPs. I have not found any clear statement of which places allow bound CPs, which support embedded CPs and which allow neither. Also I have not found any built in support for CPs in user-written plugins or extraction rules or validation rules. My approach has been to try using CPs wherever I need them and, when they do not work, write my own code that does what is needed.

You might write your own validation rule as described in [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms182556(v=vs.120)). The code could be based on the following code **which has not been tested**.

```
public class FindCpValueInResponseBody : ValidateResponseUrl
{
    public string CpWithTextToFind { get; set; }

    public override void Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        string TextToFind = e.WebTest.Context[CpWithTextToFind].ToString();

        e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult("Looking for '" + TextToFind +"' (from CP '" + CpWithTextToFind + "').");

        if (e.Response.BodyString.Contains(TextToFind))
        {
            e.IsValid = true;
            e.Message = "Text '" + TextToFind + "' found.";
        }
        else
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            e.Message = "Text '" + TextToFind + "' not found.";
        }
    }
}
```

It should be a simple matter to enhance the above method to add the other properties of the built-in `FindText` validation rule; properties such as `Pass if text found` and `Ignore case` etc, should they be needed.

The above validation rule takes the context parameter name. So if the value is from a data source then the value should be something like `DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId`. Note that there are no curly braces (i.e. no `{` or `}`) and no leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i created a custom validation rule and in web test , called that validation rule and passed the context parameter.I face the same issue.value not binding with data source.Here is the details i did:1}Created a custom validation rule(same as above)2)In web test called this validation rule3)For "CpWithTextToFind" pass value {{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}}.Tests are failing.When i give direct value in this field(value available in this table), my tests pass.any suggestions? @AdrianHHH

Comment: @DreamsOnCloud The error message (that you have not shown) should have made it clear that the CP `{{DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId}}` was not found. So you should have used the actual CP, i.e. `DataSource1.Table#csv.objectId`. Error messages are there to help you. Please read them carefully.

Comment: @AdrianHHH.....Thank you so much for your help.It is working for me now.